# Control IIS Caching via Web.config

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis-6

Is there a way to control IIS 6.0 caching via Application web.config?

Reason I ask is the fact I have dedicated box, but I do not have access to advanced IOIS settings.

Thanks

Comment: IIS 6 does not support caching control through web.config, it was introduced in later version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research this is what I have found out.

IIS 6.0 doe snot have much cash optimization. It is done for you "automagically". Therefore to control its behaviour using web.config is not possible.

Higher IIS verisons such as 70 and 7.5 have  tag that you can use in web.config.

Disclaimer:
I might wrote down wrong versions of IIS, but I am 100% certain that 6.0 cant be controlled via web.config.

Thank